# How to use multiple response in ng-repeat angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, pug

```
$http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/api/getnewgroup'
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.groups = response.data;
            }, function (response) {
                window.location.href = '/';
            });

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/api/getnewgroupforprofsms'
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.profsmsgroups.groups = response.data;
        }, function (response) {
            window.location.href = '/';
        });
```

I got two various response in $scope.groups and $scope.profsmsgroups.groups two multiple scopes.

```
tr(ng-repeat='group in profsmsgroups.groups')
   td
   input(type = 'checkbox', ng-model='group.select')
   td {{group.groupname}}
   td {{group.contactsCount}}
```

I have groupname in $scope.profsmsgroups.groups scope, so td {{group.groupname}} is displaying correctly

but i have contactsCount in $scope.groups

So how to use multiple ng-repeat response?

my $scope.profsms.groups json:

```
[
    {
        "id": 7,
        "groupname": "Angular",
        "createdAt": "2017-12-07T10:49:31.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2017-12-07T10:49:31.000Z",
        "contactgroups": [
            {
                "id": 7,
                "contact": {
                    "gsm": "4779306474"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "groupname": "Vue",
        "createdAt": "2017-12-05T09:36:15.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2017-12-05T09:36:15.000Z",
        "contactgroups": []
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "groupname": "React",
        "createdAt": "2017-12-05T09:36:29.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2017-12-07T10:46:28.000Z",
        "contactgroups": []
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "groupname": "Node",
        "createdAt": "2017-12-06T09:47:24.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2017-12-07T10:46:35.000Z",
        "contactgroups": []
    }
]
```

my $scope.groups response

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "groupname": "Vue",
        "contactsCount": 0,
        "contactgroups": []
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "groupname": "React",
        "contactsCount": 0,
        "contactgroups": []
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "groupname": "Node",
        "contactsCount": 0,
        "contactgroups": []
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "groupname": "Angular",
        "contactsCount": 1,
        "contactgroups": [
            {
                "id": 7
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: I think you need to use `$index` as `groups[$index].contactsCount`, which sounds simple, except that both arrays arrive asynchronously and I'm guessing, to sync them, you probably need to work with `$q.all()`

Comment: $index not workings, how get two  $scope.profsmsgroups.groups and $scope.groups ,(how to get two scope values in one ng-repeat? is it possible?

Comment: @MohamedSameer can you add sample data for both $scope.profsmsgroups and $scope.groups

Comment: groups[$index].contactsCount yes sorry, its worked :)

Comment: is it good approach to use this?

Comment: `groups[$index].contactsCount` doesn't sound a good approach as data in  both array needs to be in same order do you have something common between the two like groupid?

Comment: yes i have common group id

Comment: how to use this now? i have common group id

Comment: Get both arrays at the same time with `$q.all(array_of_promises)`. Process your results by merging those arrays in a loop with `new_array.push(angular.extend(array1[i],array2[i]));`. Display with `ng-repeat="group in new_array"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have comment id between the two than you can achieve it like:-

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope, $timeout) {
$scope.groups=[
{
    "id": 3,
    "groupname": "Vue",
    "contactsCount": 0,
    "contactgroups": []
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "groupname": "React",
    "contactsCount": 0,
    "contactgroups": []
},
{
    "id": 6,
    "groupname": "Node",
    "contactsCount": 0,
    "contactgroups": []
},
{
    "id": 7,
    "groupname": "Angular",
    "contactsCount": 1,
    "contactgroups": [
        {
            "id": 7
        }
    ]
}
];
$scope.pGroups=[
{
    "id": 7,
    "groupname": "Angular",
    "createdAt": "2017-12-07T10:49:31.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2017-12-07T10:49:31.000Z",
    "contactgroups": [
        {
            "id": 7,
            "contact": {
                "gsm": "4779306474"
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "groupname": "Vue",
    "createdAt": "2017-12-05T09:36:15.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2017-12-05T09:36:15.000Z",
    "contactgroups": []
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "groupname": "React",
    "createdAt": "2017-12-05T09:36:29.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2017-12-07T10:46:28.000Z",
    "contactgroups": []
},
{
    "id": 6,
    "groupname": "Node",
    "createdAt": "2017-12-06T09:47:24.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2017-12-07T10:46:35.000Z",
    "contactgroups": []
}
];
$scope.getContactCount=function(group){
var match=$scope.groups.find(function(d){return d.id==group.id})
if(match){
return match.contactsCount
}
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<table  style="width:100%">
<tr>
<th>name</th>
  <th>count</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="g in pGroups">
  <td style="text-align: center;">{{g.groupname}}</td>
  <td style="text-align: center;">{{getContactCount(g)}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: @MohamedSameer check out updated ans working fine with actual data

Comment: @MohamedSameer best approch will be to send customize data from backend so that you don't have to send two request

Comment: sry bro i have no idea about node.js :)

Comment: bro, its working good :) but i got this error in my chrome console: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined"

Comment: this means that your $scope.groups are `undefined`

Comment: But my response is correctly working, i got response, but in my console it is showing :'(

Comment: log to console just before `$scope.groups.find` line and see what you get

Comment: page doing onload, while during first load i am getting undefined, but after sometime i got data in console.log

Comment: you have to call  the method after values comes not onload

Comment: i cant understand? be specific, is i want to change above code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161694/discussion-between-jitender-and-mohamed-sameer).